# Retrieve JavaScript file from URL and access variable in Java

Tags: javascript, java

What in trying to do is access a JavaScript file from a URL and read a specific variable in Java.

The script I want to access is here: 192.99.47.179:8125/js/chatbox.js

Basically I want to log the messages which appear in the ChatBox to a file in Java. I can take care of the logging, I just have no clue how to access the script. 
NOTE: I am VERY new to accessing information on the web via Java, so a ton of comments will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're looking for an HTTP client.

Comment: if you have some code to post, we can [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's the problem, I have no clue where to start as I've never messed with retrieving info from the web via Java

Comment: It sounds like you want to run the script in Java, or see the result of doing so. This seems very misguided. JavaScript and Java are two very different, unrelated languages, despite the misleading name of JavaScript. This script is meant to be run in a browser.
Please tell us the bigger problem you are trying to solve, as you are probably approaching it wrong.

Comment: I want to take a Java program and retrieve information that is on a website. The specific information that I'm aiming for is in JavaScript (see link in OP). If the information was stored in JSON I could figure it out, but I have no clue how to retrieve JavaScript info.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are using dynmap for minecraft right? Instead of trying to retrieve the data from the javascript file, dynmap has a specific API that allows you to retrieve the messages in from the webchat

[Dynmap Wiki](https://github.com/webbukkit/dynmap/wiki#for-developers)

[Dynmap API - DynmapWebChatEvent](https://github.com/webbukkit/dynmap-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dynmap/DynmapWebChatEvent.java)

From the `DynmapWebChatEvent` you can just add the event to your listener

```
public class YourPluginListener implements Listener {
   @EventHandler
   public void onWebChat(DynmapWebChatEvent event) {
       String message = event.getMessage();
   }
}
```

Hope this was what you were looking for

Comment: Normally that would work, but the actual server and dynmap webserver are two completely different machines.